# MySQL MATCH...AGAINST sometimes finds answer, sometimes doesn't

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search

The following two queries return the same (expected) result when I query my database:

```
SELECT * FROM articles 
 WHERE content LIKE '%Euskaldunak%'

SELECT * FROM articles 
 WHERE MATCH (content) AGAINST ('+"Euskaldunak"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The text in the content field that it's searching looks like this: "...These Euskaldunak, or newcomers..."

However, the following query on the same table returns the expected single result:

```
SELECT * FROM articles 
 WHERE content LIKE '%PCC%'
```

And the following query returns an empty result:

```
SELECT * FROM articles 
 WHERE MATCH (content) AGAINST ('+"PCC"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The text in the content field that matches this result looks like this: "...Portland Community College (PCC) is the largest..."

I can't figure out why searching for "Euskaldunak" works with that MATCH...AGAINST syntax but "PCC" doesn't.  Does anyone see something that I'm not seeing?

(Also: "PCC" is not a common phrase in this field - no other rows contain the word, so the natural language search shouldn't be excluding it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your fulltext minimum word length is probably set too high. I think the default is 4, which would explain what you are seeing. Set it to 1 if you want all words indexed regardless of length.

Run this query:

```
show variables like 'ft_min_word_len';
```

If the values is greater than 3 and you want to get hits on words shorter than that, edit your /etc/my.cnf and add or update this line in the [mysqld] section using a value appropriate for your application:

```
ft_min_word_len = 1
```

Then restart MySQL and rebuild your fulltext indexes and you should be all set.

Comment: This is it!  Unfortunately I can't change the variable myself, I have to request that it be changed, so I haven't tried out the solution yet.  But the setting is, in fact, set to 4, not 3.

Comment: thanks you ike walker. note: for rebuild mysql fulltext indexes: stackoverflow.com/questions/30051510 `ANALYZE TABLE table_name`

Answer (score 4):

There are two things I can think of right away. The first is your ft_min_word_len value is set to more than 3 characters. Any "word" less than the ft_min_word_len length will not get indexed.

The second is that more then 50% of your records contain the 'PCC' string. A full text search that matches more than 50% of the records is considered irrelevant and returns nothing.

Full text indexes have different rules than regular string indexes. For example, there is a stop words list so certain common words like to, the, and, don't get indexed.